# Does the ECMA6 module system decrease the amount of raw code downloaded?

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

Say I have the following example...

```
//------ lib.js ------
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}

//------ main.js ------
import { square } from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
```

When I use SystemJS or some other module loader, does it only download the JS for square? Or does it download the whole file including `diag`? The SystemJS is loaded on the client side so it is confusing me as to how that would work. Wouldn't it create more TCP requests and slow things down a bit?

I am a bit confused by how switching to this module pattern will create a smaller footprint (requests, bandwidth, etc) then a minified and concated JS file.

Comment: Unless you use a serverside module serving system that can split files apart, this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

A module system (*any* module system) can't download partial files. It will download the whole file and parse it completely, then, depending on loader features and implementation it might reduce memory footprint to only use what's needed.

Reduced bandwidth & requests are the result of client cache. When you concatenate and minify, modules that exist in several pages are not being cached all because they're incorporated into the full concatenated script.

Comment: Actually reading through it again, I think what you are saying is that if you are concating only what needs to be hosted then the cache will be different of both pages. Our old approach was to concat and serve all code for all pages (used or not) so that we could have the browser cache our specific js file. I can appreciate that client side caching can eliminate some of these requests but I still wonder if it isn't better to cache and host 1 file instead of 100. I could see the advantages if multiple domains have the same js file and the cache works across them.

Comment: Also add a TLDR The answer is not on the client if you don't mind

Comment: To be fair, a module loader *could* use streaming for download, parsing and compilation of a module and stop after the necessary parts are loaded (speculating that the rest of the module does not contain a syntax error), similar to how browsers do parse HTML today. But you're right, ES6 modules make this speculation hard, and System.js does definitely not use such an approach.

Comment: @Bergi - "*speculating that the rest of the module does not contain a syntax error*" - or anything that affects the imported identifier, either by providing necessary functions and variables, or replacing the exported reference altogether... sounds to me like quite a fortune-teller of a loader.

Comment: @Amit: That's what I meant by "ES6 modules make this hard" :-) In a "pure" module (that does not mutate its exports, e.g. where everything is `export const …`) it still would be possible. The intra-module dependencies could be met by the same load-and-parse-only-what's-necessary algorithm.